# How to use wait_for function in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am pretty new to discord.py and i wanted to ask how to use the wait_for command to wait for a message from the author of the previous command sent to the bot? I am sorry if this makes no sense btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at discord.py documentations, it has a pretty good example for your needs

Anyways here is how you do it

```py
# wait for a message, accept it only if message's author id == command's author id
msg = await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author.id == ctx.author.id)

# get content
msg.content
# get id
msg.id
```

Comment: thx m8 this answered my question really well.

Comment: so then if i wanted to check if the author of the message is in fact the author of the command, and check the message's content at the same time, would I do something like 
if msg and msg.content == 'content': code?

Comment: you would do `check=lambda m: m.author.id == ctx.author.id and m.content == "content"`

Answer (score 1):

Waiting for a user reply:

content_copy

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$greet'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Say hello!')

        def check(m):
            return m.content == 'hello' and m.channel == channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await channel.send('Hello {.author}!'.format(msg))
```

Waiting for a thumbs up reaction from the message author:

```
content_copy
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$thumb'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Send me that  reaction, mate')

        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''

        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.send('')
        else:
            await channel.send('')
```

Comment: Note that the check function takes in the same parameter as the `on_event` function. i.e the check for a message event takes the `message` as parameter.